# Tag score is too high to fit in

Tags: bug, design

[Jon Skeets](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet?tab=topactivity#user-panel-tags) [C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23) score is too high to fit into the container `div.answer-votes` in the tags section.

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Issue still persists with new updated UI:

[image]

Comment: (Preemptively) let's not hijack the comments and make Jon Skeet jokes.

Comment: Seems that the width is set at 25px. Changing it to 30px fixes it.

Comment: @gunr2171 but for how long?

Comment: I prefer min-width: 25px; width: auto; — but I'm not sure where else it's being used that might be unexpectedly impacted.

Comment: @MattBall Probably OK at 30px until 999k, not sure if it will got to 1000k or 1M after that.